# cannot use a variable defined in an IF statement in other places in the code

Tags: php

I am having a problem with the following code.
i have seen this topic was vastly mentioned in this forum, still i could not find a solution.
what i cannot figure out is why in all the scenarios the code functions right, and the comments $comment 1 and $comment2 are approachable from the next if statement that sends the form back to the user, but only in one if statment (stated by a note in the code) this does not happen correctly.
Thank you for your time and effort.

```
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$veremail = $_POST['veremail'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
// All these variables receive values from a form

// The following IF() statements are supposed to answer all the possible
// outcomes of an email verification script, which checks if the email
// address was entered in two different fields in the same way

 if ($email===$veremail and !empty($email) and !empty($veremail)){
    $comment1='';
    $comment2=''; 

}
if ($email===$veremail and empty($email) and empty($veremail)){
    $comment1='*Please type';
    $comment2='*Please type'; 

 }

//The next if statement is the one i am having trouble with, whenever the code
//in this statement is executed, $comment 1 and $comment 2 are not displayed
//in the if statement that resend the user to the form when a problem of typing
//the data was encountered** 

     if($email!=$veremail and !empty($email) and !empty($veremail)){
        $comment1='*email addresses not match';
        $comment2='*email addresses not match'; 

     }**
 if ($email!=$veremail and !empty($email) and empty($veremail)){
    $comment1='';
    $comment2='*Please type'; 

 }
 if($email!=$veremail and empty($email) and !empty($veremail)){
    $comment1='*Please type';
    $comment2='';
 }

echo    $comment1.' ' .$comment2;  //I added this to make sure these variables
// received the expected value by the preceding if statements, I never
// encounterd a problem in here: the expected values were always presented
// correctly here

 /* 
The next code checks variables submitted from form customer feedback

 This next code analyses the variables submitted by the form using the
 empty() function If any of them are empty it will return the client to
 the form, the values which were already typed are kept and a note next
 to a field which was not submitted is added

 */

if (    empty($fname) 
    OR  empty($fname) 
    OR  empty($lname) 
    OR  empty($email) 
    OR  empty($veremail) 
    OR  empty($subject) 
    OR  empty($message) 
    OR  $email!=$veremail){
echo "
<center>    \n
<br><br><br>\n
<h1>Your feed back please</h1>\n
<Br><br>\n
    \t<form action=".'feedbackprocess.php'." method=".'POST'.">\n
    \t\t<table>\n
    \t\t\t      <tr>\n
    \t\t\t\t        <td>First name:             </td>           <td><input type=".'text'." name=".'fname'." value="."$fname".">";
                    if(empty($fname)){
                    echo "*please fill";
                    }
                    echo"</td>\n
    \t\t\t      </tr>\n
    \t\t\t      <tr>\n
    \t\t\t\t        <td>Last name:              </td>           <td><input type=".'text'." name=".'lname'." value="."$lname".">";
                    if(empty($lname)){
                    echo "*please fill";
                    }
                    echo"</td>\n
    \t\t\t      </tr>\n
    \t\t\t      <tr>\n
    \t\t\t\t        <td>Email address:          </td>           <td><input type=".'text'." name=".'email'." value="."$email".">";
                    if(empty($email)){
                    echo "$comment1";
                    }
                    echo"</td>\n
                </tr>\n
    \t\t\t      <tr>\n
    \t\t\t\t        <td>Verify email address:   </td>           <td><input type=".'text'." name=".'veremail'." value="."$veremail".">";
                    if(empty($veremail)){
                    echo "$comment2";
                    }
                    echo"</td>\n
    \t\t\t      <tr>\n
                <tr>\n
    \t\t\t\t        <td>Subject:                </td>           <td><input type=".'text'." name=".'subject'." value="."$subject".">";
                    if(empty($subject)){
                    echo "*please fill";
                    }
                    echo"</td>\n
    \t\t\t      </tr>\n
    \t\t</table>\n
        <br><br>\n
                            Content:<br>\n

                    <textarea rows=".'6'." cols=".'50'." name=".'message'.">$message"."</textarea>";
                    if(empty($message)){
                    echo "<br><br>*please fill";
                    }
                    echo"
                    <br><br>\n
                    <input type=".'submit'.">\n
                    </form>\n
</center>\n
";
}else{
echo 'Thank you for your comment';
}
```

Comment: This seems very sloppy and there is surely a better way to manage your different possible scenarios.

Comment: Hey Dan.I am sure there is a more elegant way.  I am doing this as an exercise, trying to learn php, and and using this examples i try to gain a more profound understating of why a variable behaves like it does. I am very new to this:)

Comment: I think it would be worthwhile to start over / rewrite this.

Comment: How it "does not happen correctly" ? What is the output of the `echo` in that case ?

Comment: Hey brewal. In this case the output of both $comment1 and $comment 2 is "*email addresses not match", yet it is only presented the time i echoed it, but later on next to the form field of the email it is not presented

Answer (score 0):

Check one thing at a time, and don't chain with `AND` when it's not necessary.

Something like this is likely not what you want:

```
if (empty($email) and empty($veremail)) {
     // Handle error
}
```

This will only be fired if both `$email` and `$veremail` are empty! So if only one field is empty, the program doesn't register an error.

Let's look at the `if` clause giving you trouble, namely the following:

```
 if($email!=$veremail and !empty($email) and !empty($veremail)){
    $comment1='*email addresses not match';
    $comment2='*email addresses not match'; 
 }
```

The problem here is that you just want to check if `$email != $veremail`. Check that the variables aren't empty beforehand, and then we don't have to worry about the variables being empty anymore. One step at a time. :)

Something like this will do the trick. Notice the `or` instead of the `and`. First we check that `$email` and `$veremail` aren't empty, and then we check that they're equal to each other.

```
if (empty($email) or empty($veremail)) {
    $comment = '*Please type';
}
else if ($email !== $veremail) {
    $comment = '*Email addresses did not match';
}
```

Comment: This solution works, yet it does not answer what i do not understand:  since the problematic if clause does insert the value **"*email addresses not match"** into the variable **$comment1** and **$comment2** when the condition i specified is met, and i know that it worked since i echo the values of these variables immediately after the if clause, still it does not present this value later in the code. meanwhile with all the other scenarios it works just as expected. **What i am trying to figure out is why isent it working, is there a scope problem which i do not understand?**

Comment: If you use multiple `if` (not `else if`) the variables `$comment1` and `$comment2` will be overwritten with whatever last error message is assigned to them.

Answer (score 0):

In the response field :

> `if(empty($email)){
>      echo "$comment1";
>   }`

And

> `if(empty($veremail)){
>       echo "$comment2";
>   }`

It will hide the comments because both fields are not empty thus it hides the comments.
Try using

> `if($comment){
>      echo "$comment1";
>   }`

This code will display only if there is anything inside the $comment variable.

Note.. it better to use :

> `if($variable}{}`

To check if the variable has any data in it.To return false if filled just use :

> `if(!$variable}{}`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you all for your solutions, I learned a lot from them**. 
The problem was logical:

The first condition which was supposed to enter the value **email addresses not match** to the variable **$comment1** is this:

```
if($email!=$veremail and !empty($email) and !empty($veremail)){
        $comment1='*email addresses not match';
        $comment2='*email addresses not match';
```

However when i wanted to display these comments when the user was refered back to the form this was the code:

```
<tr>
    <td>Email address:</td>           
    <td><input type=".'text'." name=".'email'." value="."$email".">";
                        if(empty($email)){
                        echo "$comment1";
                        }
    echo"</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>Verify email address:</td>           
     <td><input type=".'text'." name=".'veremail'." value="."$veremail".">";
                        **if(empty($veremail)){
                        echo "$comment2";
                        }**
      echo"</td>
<tr>
```

This condition did not allow the comments **$comment1 and $comment2** to be displayed, and when the condition was removed the problem was solved.